# regex masked input for latitude and longitude with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, input, latitude-longitude, mask

I'm trying to mask an input specifically for latitude and longitude values with jQuery. I started searching for a regex value to validate each of them, and hopefully I found these:

```
for latitude
/^-?([0-8]?[0-9]|90)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/
for longitude
/^-?((1?[0-7]?|[0-9]?)[0-9]|180)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/
```

Also I found a function to mask an input with regex as below:

```
$(this).keypress(function(event){
    if(!event.charCode){
        return true;
    }
    var part1 = this.value.substring(0,this.selectionStart);
    var part2 = this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd,this.value.length);
    if(!mask.test(part1 + String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) + part2)){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now when I check values like `/^-?([0-8]?[0-9]|90)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/.test("44.4")` the validation returns `true` but what I want to accomplish here is to validate these inputs as the user is typing.

For example I start by inputting 4:

```
/^-?([0-8]?[0-9]|90)\.[0-9]{1,6}$/.test("4") returns false;
```

and therefore the input gets no value.

Comment: What's wrong here?

Comment: What needs more explanation?

Comment: I see you did everything you want listening for an event and validating input or I can't find the problem.

Comment: The issue is that the regex doesn't appear to match the value which is shorter than xx.x

Comment: For example I press any number on keyboard, the regex returns false, and input gets no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latitute: `/^(?:-|-?(?:\d|[1-8]\d?|90?)(?:\.[0-9]{0,6})?)$/`

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      - 
   |  
      -? 
      (?:
           \d 
        |  [1-8] \d? 
        |  90?
      )
      (?: \. [0-9]{0,6} )?
 )
 $
```

Longitude: `/^(?:-|-?(?:\d|[1-9]\d?|1(?:[0-7]\d?)?|1(?:80?)?)(?:\.[0-9]{0,6})?)$/`

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      - 
   |  
      -?     
      (?:
           \d 
        |  [1-9] \d? 
        |  1 
           (?: [0-7] \d? )?
        |  1
           (?: 80? )?
      )
      (?: \. [0-9]{0,6} )?
 )
 $
```

24 Hour Time:  `^(?:\d|0\d?|1\d?|2[0-3]?)(?::(?:\d|0\d?|[1-5]\d?)?)?$`

```
 ^     
 (?:
      \d                  #  0 -  9
   |  0 \d?               # 00 - 09
   |  1 \d?               # 10 - 19
   |  2 [0-3]?            # 20 - 23
 )
 (?:
      :                   # :
      (?:
           \d             #  0 -  9
        |  0 \d?          # 00 - 09
        |  [1-5] \d?      # 10 - 59
      )?
 )?
 $
```

Comment: Thank you, the lookahead did the trick, can you help me further for handling the optional "-" at the beginning?

Comment: yes when the input value is EXACTLY "-" it returns false again, but for positive numbers it works ok.

Comment: You are awesome!

Comment: I can't thank you enough but the first regex for latitude doesn't get the second digit before the dot "."

Comment: Ok, I added possible `-` only. What else doesn't work ?

Comment: /^(?:-|-?(?:\d|[1-8]\d?|90?)(?:\.[0-9]{0,6})?)$/ this one lacks the second digit, I'm messing with it like /^(?:-$|-?)(?:\d|[1-8]?[1-8]\d?|90?)(?:\.[0-9]{0,6})?$/

Comment: No, use the last regexes I posted. They all work I think.

Comment: sorry but can you help me out with the same idea but for the 24 hour time input?/^(?:(?:2?[0-3]|1?[0-9]|0?[0-9]?):?([0-5][0-9]?)?)$/

Comment: @CenaEbrahimiyan - Added one for _Time_.

Answer (score 0):

In other words while the user types you want an input that would otherwise be invalid to pass? Why not just check after the input looses focus? Or you could use some sort of timer from the last key typed.

Comment: As I'm working on it further, I noticed if I tweak the regex it is possible, but I'm not yet successful.